# C# class member function pointer and c++ this->*func

Tags: c#, pointers, delegates, this

I'm porting a C++ project to C# and have a problem with a this->function pointer.
In C++ it works well:

```
class ModbusData {
bool ScannAll(void (ModbusData::*func)(MBSFrame *Frame), MBSFrame *Frame)
{
    if (Frame->MatchAddress(MyBaseAddr, MySize)) {
        (this->*func) (Frame);
        return true;
    } else {
        if (NextData != 0) {
            return NextData->ScannAll(func, Frame);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

};

// usage of the function is like follows

```
gCoils->ScannAll(&ModbusData::ReadMultiple, Frame);
```

This is my C# atrempt:

```
class ModbusData {
    public delegate void ModDataFunc(MBSFrame Frame);
    public bool ScannAll(ModDataFunc func, MBSFrame Frame)
    {
        if (Frame.MatchAddress(MyBaseAddr, MySize)) {
            func.Invoke(Frame);
            RaiseValueReadEvent(Frame.DataAddress, Frame.DataCount);
            return true;
        } else {
            if (NextData != null) {
            return NextData.ScannAll(func, Frame);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
};

//  usage
gCoils.ScannAll(gCoils.ReadMultiple, Frame);
```

The problem is obvoisly the recursive call with the next instace of the class
NextData.ScannAll(func, Frame);
Because the class member variables are no longer valid.

I have learned in C# the delegate function is somewhat static. A solution could be to pass also the class reference.
But maybe sombody has a better idea.

Comment: Comments on porting -- Your attempt of porting is the reason why attempting to do line-by-line and/or module-by-module translations from language A to language B will fail.   C++ has its way of doing things, C# has its ways, and those ways can be vastly different to achieve the same goal.  In addition, trying to make language B look like language A will almost always result in language B having inefficient code, buggy code, or code that looks plain weird to someone who knows language B.

Comment: In C#, a delegate can point to both a static or a member function. In case of the later, the object reference is included in the delegate. So that is likely not the problem. What error do you get?

Comment: It's not obvious what the problem is. Is there an error? Is something not working as expected? Even the recursion isn't obvious. A class named `ModbusData` has a method called `ScannAll` that calls a method with the same name in a different class.

Comment: in C#, when calling  ScannAll(), I use a pointer (delegate) to a specific instance of the class (gCoils.ReadMultiple), where in C++ the pointer is  as relaive address base to the class definition  (&ModbusData::ReadMultiple). Later in ScannAll() the (this->*func)() makes the magic. Be aware ScannAll() make a recusive call with another instance of the ModbusData class.  
I forgot to explain that there a some class member vaiables (MyBaseAddr, MySize) which in C# no longer valid at  that moment when calling NextData.ScannAll()

Answer (score 1):

You could create another delegate that takes `ModbusData` and `MBSFrame` which is not bound to a specified target and pass the current instance to it.

```
public delegate void ModDataFunc(MBSFrame Frame);
private delegate void StaticModDataFunc(ModbusData ths, MBSFrame Frame);

private bool ScannAll(StaticModDataFunc func, MBSFrame Frame)
{
  if (Frame.MatchAddress(MyBaseAddr, MySize))
  {
    func(this, Frame);
    RaiseValueReadEvent(Frame.DataAddress, Frame.DataCount);
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    if (NextData != null)
    {
      return NextData.ScannAll(func, Frame);
    }
    return false;
  }
}

public bool ScannAll(ModDataFunc func, MBSFrame Frame)
{
  return ScannAll(func.Method.CreateDelegate<StaticModDataFunc>(), Frame);
}
```

Comment: Indeed  that is what I mentioned before,  passing the this pointer with member function. But at this moment my member function gets static because the related class is in the argument list. To get my problem more clear I will create a new question.

Comment: it does not become static, the first argument becomes the this pointer.