# C# calling member function with delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686405/c-sharp-class-member-function-pointer-and-c-this-func) post I create a new question to make  my probleme more clear. I have a class with a next class member, so there will be a daisy chain of class instances. A function in my class calls another member function or all  instances in the chain.

c ++ has a resonable solution for this problem. In C# I tried it with a delegate. I made a short program to show what I mean.

```
    class Program  {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DaisyChain TestClass = new DaisyChain(1);
            TestClass.AddClass(new DaisyChain(2));
            TestClass.AllprintID();
        }
    }

    class DaisyChain  {
        private int ClassID;
        private DaisyChain NextClass;

        public DaisyChain(int ID) {ClassID = ID; }

        public void AddClass(DaisyChain newClass) {
            if (NextClass == null) {
                NextClass = newClass;
            } else {
                NextClass.AddClass(newClass);
            }
        }
        public void AllprintID()  {
            DoForEach(this.printID);
        }

        public delegate void doFunc();
        public void DoForEach (doFunc aMemberFunc)  {
            aMemberFunc();
            if (NextClass != null) {
                NextClass.DoForEach(aMemberFunc);
            }
        }

        public void printID() {
            Console.WriteLine(ClassID);
        }
    };
```

This example do not work correct, because the class instance is not part of the function call.

I can add a class argumnet to my member function and chang the delegate,

```
       public void printID(DaisyChain me) {
            Console.WriteLine(me.ClassID);
        }
```

but then the function will be static and no longer usable in the normal way.
I would be happy if ther another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate type *should* have an extra argument, since you want to call `printID` on different objects. You can either add one to `doFunc`, or just use the built in [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0) delegate type.

```
public void DoForEach (Action<DaisyChain> aMemberFunc)  {
    aMemberFunc(this);
    if (NextClass != null) {
        NextClass.DoForEach(aMemberFunc);
    }
}
```

When calling `DoForEach`, you can either pass a lambda expression:

```
public void AllprintID()  {
    DoForEach(x => x.printID());
}
```

Or if you really like the method group syntax for some reason, write a local function `printID`:

```
public void AllprintID()  {
    void PrintID(DaisyChain chain) {
        chain.PrintID();
    }
    DoForEach(PrintID);
}

// method names should start with a capital letter :)
public void PrintID() {
    Console.WriteLine(ClassID);
}
```

Other code can still call `PrintID` as usual - code outside `AllprintID` won't even notice the local function.

Comment: The action<T> delegate type in conjunction with the lambda expression seems for me the best solution- Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Check [LinkedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-6.0) and [LinkedListNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlistnode-1?view=net-6.0) in the documentation. Here is an example to get you on the way:

```
    var daisyChain = new DaisyChain();
    daisyChain.Add(1);
    daisyChain.Add(2);

    class DaisyChain: LinkedList<DaisyChainLink>
    {
        public void Add(int id) => AddLast(new LinkedListNode<DaisyChainLink>(new DaisyChainLink(id)));

        public void Print()
        {
            var link = this.First;
            link?.Value.Print();
            while (null != link?.Next)
            {
                link = link.Next;
                link?.Value.Print();
            }
        }
    }

    class DaisyChainLink
    {
        public DaisyChainLink(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
        
        public int Id { get; }

        public void Print() => Console.WriteLine(Id);
    }
```

Comment: The LinkedList dosn't solve my real problem. Be aware my goal is to invoke different methodes of the class for all instances in the chain. So in the linkedlist I need again a delegate and have the same problem.

Comment: Instead of a delegate you could use a visitor. Here is a good explanation of the visitor pattern.